# Black background is automatically set for xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors, background

If you create a new xml file, its background color automatically turns black. How can I disable this so that it is always white?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8eMw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background of an activity is automatically set in its theme. Go to your styles file in the styles folder and add a new item in your default app style. i.e

```
   <style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    
   </style>
```

White becomes the default background color of xml layouts in your app